# Dynamically add rows that can be search-filtered from a list using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I have a list of items, generated by PHP that is quite long. I don't want to show this list in a dropdown menu. Instead, I'm using jquery to have users type in a textbox, then filtering from that list based on user input:

Example HTML:

```
<table id = "table">
    <tr>
        <td>Select an animal:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id = "animal" name="animal" placeholder="Choose an animal...">
        <td id="animals">
        <span class="animal_list">
            <p onclick="insertme('horse')">Horse</p>
        </span>
        <span class="animal_list">
            <p onclick="insertme('goat')">Goat</p>
        </span>
        <span class="animal_list">
            <p onclick="insertme('sheep')">Sheep</p>
        </span>
        <span class="animal_list">
            <p onclick="insertme('cow')">Cow</p>
        </span>
        </div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And the CSS to hide the list:

```
#animals .animal_list {
    display: none;
}
```

JQuery filter:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#animal').keyup(function() {
      var search = this.value.split(';');
      $('.animal_list').each(function(index, element) {
        var text = $(element).text().toLowerCase();
        var show = search.filter(function(e) {
            return e != '' && text.indexOf(e.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
        }).length > 0;
        $(element).toggle(show);
      });
    });
});
```

And here's some JavaScript that allows users to click on the option to input it in the textbox:

```
function insertme(label){
    document.getElementById('animal').value = label;
    
    //when selected, hide all of variable 1 list            
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("animal_list");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i].style.display = "none";
    };      
}
```

This works great as is. However, for my application, the users need to be able to duplicate rows dynamically. My idea was to copy the html from the div (the "animals" div) and repeat it for every row:

```
function add_row(ID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(ID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    
    // insert a row label
// insert a row label
var col1 = row.insertCell(0);
col1.innerHTML = "Select an animal:"

// second column...
    // insert a search box
    var col2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element = document.createElement("input");
        element.type = "text";
        element.name = "animal";
    col2.appendChild(element);
    
    // get the existing elements
    var existing_list = document.getElementById("animals");
    
    // create new object (so I can delete the first)
    var list_copy = existing_list
    
    // delete old list so it's not duplicating jquery effect across all rows
    existing_list.remove();
    
    //append list to new row
    col2.appendChild(list_copy);
    
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. The second row doesn't filter based on the list anymore. According to my development console, the div does indeed get deleted from the first row, then inserted in the second row, but the list of items is not displaying based on user input. In other words, the JQuery filtering stops working at the second row.

Any ideas how to fix this? I'm happy to abandon my approach if there's a better way (i.e., better than copying a div to a new row and deleting the div associated with the original row).

(P.S. sorry for slovenly mixing JavaScript with JQuery. I'm a bit of a noob with both).

Putting it all together:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function add_row(ID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(ID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    
    // insert a row label
    var col1 = row.insertCell(0);
    col1.innerHTML = "Select an animal:"
    
    // second column...
        // insert a search box
        var col2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var element = document.createElement("input");
            element.type = "text";
            element.name = "animal";
        col2.appendChild(element);
        
        // get the existing elements
        var existing_list = document.getElementById("animals");
        
        // create new object (so I can delete the first)
        var list_copy = existing_list
        
        // delete old list so it's not duplicating jquery effect across all rows
        existing_list.remove();
        
        //append list to new row
        col2.appendChild(list_copy);
    
}

function insertme(label){
    document.getElementById('animal').value = label;
    
    //when selected, hide all of variable 1 list            
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("animal_list");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i].style.display = "none";
    };      
}
    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#animal').keyup(function() {
      var search = this.value.split(';');
      $('.animal_list').each(function(index, element) {
        var text = $(element).text().toLowerCase();
        var show = search.filter(function(e) {
            return e != '' && text.indexOf(e.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
        }).length > 0;
        $(element).toggle(show);
      });
    });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
#animals .animal_list {
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id = "table">
    <tr>
        <td>Select an animal:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id = "animal" name="animal" placeholder="Choose an animal...">
        <td id="animals">
            <span class="animal_list">
                <p onclick="insertme('horse')">Horse</p>
            </span>
            <span class="animal_list">
                <p onclick="insertme('goat')">Goat</p>
            </span>
            <span class="animal_list">
                <p onclick="insertme('sheep')">Sheep</p>
            </span>
            <span class="animal_list">
                <p onclick="insertme('cow')">Cow</p>
            </span>
        </div>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" onclick="add_row('table')" value = "Add Row"> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Don't misuse `<label>`** if it does not contains or refers-to (using `for` attribute) to a FormAction Element

Comment: `col1` without `var` is the same like doing `window.col1` AKA: **bloating Window scope**.

Comment: `<div>` cannot be a direct child of `<tr>`. It's the same like using `<span>` as a `<ul>` child (instead of `<li>`).

Comment: Modified code based on the first two comments. I'm not sure how to fix the third...

Comment: `<div id="animals">` should be `<td id="animals">` with the appropriate closing tag `</td>`

Comment: changed, though the problem still exists. Thanks for helping me with proper web standards, though :)

Comment: To be honest, I'm a bit lost with your bits and pieces... :\ ;) could you please create a [mcve]?

Comment: Added. (Mostly just splicing together the stuff that was there before).

Comment: Use event delegation.  ids must be unique.  if they will repeat, you should be using class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML for each row was incorrect.

- Unclosed tags and hanging end tags.  I've adjusted it so that the cells are consistent.
- `id` must be unique, so I've changed it to be `class="animals"`, which may be helpful in the future for DOM selection.

  - changed CSS style `#animals` -> `.animals`

It's important that each row is encapsulated, self-contained, and consistent so that DOM traversal can be done reliably.  This allows for code related to each DOM node to be self-contained, so you can treat them like components.  It will also help with CSS styling.

With this organization, all you have to do is `cloneNode(true)` the row to add a new one, and for the events traverse within the row to select the DOM nodes you need to target.

I've used [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to attach a single event to the table that targets every `input[name="animals"]` node inside it.  So all new rows get targeted correctly.
Since all the DOM traversal and event handlers are self-contained for each row, the same event handler can be reused for all nodes.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function add_row(ID) {
      var table = document.getElementById(ID);
      var rowCount = table.rows.length;
      
      // (full) clone the last row and append to table
      table.appendChild(table.rows[rowCount - 1].cloneNode(true))

    }

    function insertme(el, label) {
      var row = $(el).closest('tr')
      row.find('input[name="animal"]')[0].value = label;

      //when selected, hide all of variable 1 list            
      var list = row[0].getElementsByClassName("animal_list");
      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i].style.display = "none";
      };
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      // event delegation on table for all inputs with name "animal"
      $('#table').on('keyup', 'input[name="animal"]', function(event) {
        var search = this.value.split(';');
        // traverse DOM to find containing row, then search for animal list nodes
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.animal_list').each(function(index, element) {
          var text = $(element).text().toLowerCase();
          var show = search.filter(function(e) {
            return e != '' && text.indexOf(e.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
          }).length > 0;
          $(element).toggle(show);
        });
      });
    });
  </script>

  <style type="text/css">
    .animals .animal_list {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <td>Select an animal:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="animal" placeholder="Choose an animal..."></td>
      <td class="animals">
            <span class="animal_list">
                <p onclick="insertme(this,'horse')">Horse</p>
            </span>
            <span class="animal_list">
                <p onclick="insertme(this,'goat')">Goat</p>
            </span>
            <span class="animal_list">
                <p onclick="insertme(this,'sheep')">Sheep</p>
            </span>
            <span class="animal_list">
                <p onclick="insertme(this,'cow')">Cow</p>
            </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <input type="button" onclick="add_row('table')" value="Add Row">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Excellent! One addition to this: I don't want the input text to copy to the next row, so I added the following to the add_row function: table.rows[rowCount].cells[1].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = "";